# Accessing part of an object using path

Tags: javascript, iteration

Have a an object as shown below:

```
const arrObj = [
{
   name: 'FolderA',
   path: '/',
   child: [
     {
       name: 'FolderB',
       path: '/FolderA',
       child: [
         {
           name: 'FolderC0',
           path: '/FolderA/FolderB',
           child: [],
         },
         {
           name: 'FolderC1',
           path: '/FolderA/FolderB',
           child: [],
         },
       ],
     },
   ],
 },
 {
   name: 'FolderM',
   path: '/',
   child: [],
 },
];
```

If I have path as string :

```
var path = '/FolderA/FolderB',
```

Will I be able to access child part of the object inside FolderB using array reduce?
Tried this with failure:

```
var res = path.split('/').reduce(function(o, k) {
 return o && o[k];
}, arrObj);
```

Comment: [There is no JSON here, only JavaScript](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)

Comment: There is no property called `FolderA`.  You need to find the object with that name.

Comment: I don't like that JSON structure to be honest. Why you need `path` properties there? I mean, how you exactly want to parse, what props are you trying to look for? EDIT: there can be multiple ways, like check if path matches or by `name` properties.

Comment: I don't like it either, but it is what I have to work with, so having path as string I somehow have to access the part of it, so I can manipulate it :(

Comment: @Nika  Seems a fine structure to me,  yes, you could argue that the `path` could be made redundant, but one advantage of storing `path` here is that the folder item could be sent to another function and the `path` is also there,  otherwise that would be lost.

Comment: @Keith that's arguable. In my opinion it should be dynamically set, not statically. It will reduce data size and only use it whenever need (the parents). Also imagine you have many array of children there and you changed parent path, you have to manually change everything by hand and so on. I see many drawbacks (just my point of view).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [Array#reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) and [Array#find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

```js
const path = '/FolderA/FolderB'
const data =[{name:'FolderA',path:'/',child:[{name:'FolderB',path:'/FolderA',child:[{name:'FolderC0',path:'/FolderA/FolderB',child:[],},{name:'FolderC1',path:'/FolderA/FolderB',child:[],},],},],},{name:'FolderM',path:'/',child:[],},]

const res = path.slice(1).split("/").reduce((a,c)=>{
  return a.find(({name})=> name === c).child;
 }, data);

console.log(res);
```

Tests:

```js
const data=[{name:'FolderA',path:'/',child:[{name:'FolderB',path:'/FolderA',child:[{name:'FolderC0',path:'/FolderA/FolderB',child:[],},{name:'FolderC1',path:'/FolderA/FolderB',child:[{name:'FolderD0',path:'/FolderA/FolderB/FolderC1',child:[]}],},],},],},{name:'FolderM',path:'/',child:[],},]

function find(path){return path.slice(1).split("/").reduce((a,c)=>a.find(({name})=>name===c).child,data)}


console.log(find("/FolderA"));
console.log(find("/FolderA/FolderB"));
//no children so should be empty
console.log(find("/FolderA/FolderB/FolderC0"));
//Not empty
console.log(find("/FolderA/FolderB/FolderC1"));
```

Comment: This won't work on deeper level. You're restricting it only for 2 levels deep. Try '/FolderA/FolderB/FolderC0' as a pth.

Comment: @Nika and why shouldn't it work past 2 levels? It returns an empty array for FolderC0 because there are no children.

Comment: I mean, even if you add array there, it will have same issue. EDIT: what I am saying is that, it should be in recursion instead of a one single reduce.

Comment: EDIT: pardon me, I had case issues here, ignore me.

Comment: @kemicofa - Thanks a lot buddy :)